# cordova plugins bluetooth background service

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, bluetooth

I'm currently trying to make an IOS app with cordova. While reading the [doc for bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) I was wondering if it was possible to have the cordova plugins to handle the "Reinstantiate Your Central and Peripheral Managers" part.

Since that part should not required to bring the app foreground to interact with the bluetooth device, will the plugin will be able to wake up ? or will the cordova part must be wake up to ?

Is there a way to simplify the implementation ?

I'm kind of new with the bluetooth technology and I don't have much knowledge with cordova plugin. I'm still currently trying to make it work but I would like to know if it is possible.

For now I'm doing the app like so:

cordova will handle the interface to setup the data and settings and the plugins will handle all the interactions with the bluetooth device. I'm trying to make the plugins, the part that will be restored when a know bluetooth device is connected (in the hope it do so even when the phone is locked) and make it handle the data transfert without the app being put in the foreground or even lunched in the background (I would like to have only the plugins part to be wake up)